# ElasticSearch : Group by field with Terms aggregation and aggregate on Min price

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation

Consider a OneToMany relation between Articles and VariationGroups.

In ElasticSearch, each article document has a "variationGroup" field.

I use a Terms aggregation to group results by the field "variationGroup" of articles documents.
I use a TopHits sub-aggregation to get the first document of each bucket.

How can I get the minimum price of each variation group ? If i use a Min sub-aggregation on my term Aggregation, minimum price will be calculated on documents that match the query.

I would like to get the minimum price for all documents that could be grouped under a variation group.

For example the VariationGroup named "Tshirt with stars" contains 6 Articles. The query "red Tshirt" returns 2 of those 6 articles.
**I would like to get the minimum price for the 6 articles and not only for the 2 articles that match the query.**

Is that even possible in the same call ?

Here is the corresponding json :

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "name": "red Tshirt"
    }
  },
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "variation_groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "variationGroup",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_price": {
          "min": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "max_price": {
          "max": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "top_article": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that's because the aggregations are applied on the matched documents only. You want to use [`post_filter`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html) instead of a normal query, that way your aggregations will run on all documents and then at the very end, only `red Tshirt` documents will be returned.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "variation_groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "variationGroup",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_price": {
          "min": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "max_price": {
          "max": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "top_article": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "post_filter": {               <---- move your query in a post_filter
      "query": {
         "match": {
            "name": "red Tshirt"
         }
      }
  }   
}
```

**UPDATE**

Based on your comment, I would do it like this:

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "variation_groups": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "variationGroup",
        "size": 0
      },
      "aggs": {
        "min_price": {
          "min": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "max_price": {
          "max": {
            "field": "price"
          }
        },
        "top_article": {
          "filter": {
            "query": {
              "match": {
                "name": "red Tshirt"
              }
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "top_article": {
              "top_hits": {
                "size": 1
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That could be a good answer but not exactly what i want, because every article document will be grouped on variationGroup field. I'm getting results from top_article aggregation that's why i specified `"size": 0` for the main query. top_article aggregation must return only `red Tshirt` documents, whereas min_price aggregation should return the min_price for the variationGroup regardless of the query "red Tshirt". I don't think i can do that in one call...

Comment: Ok I see, then what I would do is to remove `post_filter` and wrap the `top_hits` inside a `filter` aggregation so that the aggregations run on all documents but top hits would only be returned for `red Tshirt`, would that work for you?

Comment: Little mistake : you should add a "name" to the top_hits aggregation, like that : `"aggs": { "top": { "top_hits": { "size": 1 } } }`.

Comment: It does the job pretty well, but is a little too long, which is logical because every article has to be group on VariationGroup for the min_price aggregation.

Comment: Oops, sorry for the mistake, I've fixed it. What do you mean by "too long"?

Comment: I use _head_ plugin to test. I think it's the display of results which is long, because in response `took` field value is only 183ms. Response is really big, because it returns buckets that contains no `top_article`. I will implement your solution in my application and test performances afterwards. Thanks a lot for your help :)

Comment: Yes, indeed, the head plugin spends quite a bit of time parsing the response and manipulating the DOM so if the response is big then you'd definitely feel the latency. I'd advise to measure perfs directly in your application. Also you can reduce the amount of returned bytes by using [response filtering](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_response_filtering)

Comment: Good to know : `_score` returned for each doc is always 1. I assume this occur because I don't have any main query.